# set off/deploy/* the airbag

Tags: word-choice, word-request

The car hit the dumpster with enough impact to set off/deploy the airbag.

Which of "set off" and "deploy" sounds more explosive? Is there anything else I could use instead to make it sound more explosive - as it is when an airbag goes off?

Answer (score 1):

**It appears the most common words in this situation are *deploy*, *inflate*, *activate* and *trigger*.**

Here is my evidence:

[image]

*Inflate* isn't a particularly "explosive" word, and doesn't really describe the bigger picture.

*Deploy* is a very "military" word, but an airbag is not a weapon. *Deploy* is certainly more dramatic than *inflate*, though, making it a better choice.

*Activate* and *trigger* are the most accurate words to describe the action done to the airbag and caused by the impact between the car and the dumpster. I think *trigger* is the most "explosive" out of all of these suggestions (one could actually *trigger* an explosion), but *activate* is also a perfect fit.

**I suggest *trigger*.**

Answer (score 0):

if you want onomatopoeia, I doubt that you will find any formal words that will do. Words to do with setting off weapons include 'fire':

> the chip that then sends a signal to fire the airbag (Wikipedia)

or 'trigger':

> trigger the airbag (Wording of US patent)